# getting extra page count in pdf using itext api with Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have an issue with the page count in a PDF.

Suppose that we have a pdf with page count 3, but in the footer it's returning  "Page 1 Of 4". We are getting the 4 from the Eventer class.

> Jar : com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar
>
> Eventer class : PdfPageEventHelper.java

[image]

Comment: iText 2.1.7 is no longer supported. Those version dates from 2009 and you should no longer use it. Please read [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) if you need arguments to convince your project manager to upgrade to a more recent version of iText or iTextSharp.

Comment: Moreover: `PdfPageEventHelper` is an implementation of the `PdfPageEvents` interface that consists of *nothing but* **empty** *methods*. Hence your allegation that the "Eventer" class is `PdfPageEventHelper` is wrong. This means that no one has any idea what you mean by `Eventer` class. There is no such thing.

Comment: Even though if i used latest version also getting a same issue. Please check the snipping code on http://memorynotfound.com/adding-header-footer-pdf-using-itext-java/

Comment: Is there any reason why you prefer (wrong) examples from an unofficial web site instead of (correct) examples from the official web site?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the official documentation, and you'll discover that the example on the unoffical web site you consulted is wrong.

In chapter 5 of my book "iText in Action - Second Edition", you'll find the [MovieCountries1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#225-moviecountries1.java) example. As you can see, we use `writer.getPageNumber() - 1` in the `onCloseDocument()` method.

```
public void onCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
            new Phrase(String.valueOf(writer.getPageNumber() - 1)),
            2, 2, 0);
}
```

The reason for this is explained in the NOTE on page 152 of the book:

> **NOTE** When the document is closed, the `newPage()` method is triggered to
>   perform finilizations on the current page. When `newPage()` is called, the page
>   number is augmented, so you need to use `(writer.getPageNumber() - 1)` if
>   you want to add the total number of pages in the `onCloseDocument()` method.

If you need another example, take a look at the [FillTemplateHelper](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker-itext5/reporting-examples#1494-filltemplatehelper.java) example on the official web site.